# php8.1 Call to undefined function iconv

Tags: php, php-8.1

Please help me

**my source code**

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $value);
```

**error message**

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function iconv()

**server**
ubuntu : 22.04
php v : PHP 8.1.13
use : php8.1-fpm.service

I want to use the iconv function

**try**

```
apt install php8.1-common

phpenmod common

WARNING: Module common ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.1/mods-available
```

```
php-fpm8.1 -m

bcmath
cgi-fcgi
Core
curl
date
dom
filter
gd
hash
igbinary
imagick
imap
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
OAuth
openssl
pcre
redis
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sodium
SPL
standard
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

Comment: Check the Configuration options. [This extension is enabled by default, although it may be disabled by compiling with --without-iconv.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/iconv.installation.php)

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: You can check it with `php -i | grep -i config` or with `<?php phpinfo();`

Comment: Even if I check, I don't know if I use iconv